# Reading all characters until occurence of ; but noch enclosed by ""

Tags: antlr, antlr4

Ok... i have the following problem:

i need to parse (or tokenize) the following text

```
ASK "Hey dude, what's about \";\"" + "?";
ASK "How old are you?" INTO inAge;
ASK "This is a
multiline String with \";\";" + " can you parse this?"; ANSWER "Sure, i can!";
```

in lexer, i tried it with modes:

```
ASK     : 'ASK' -> pushMode(UNTILSEMI) ;
ANSWER  : 'ANSWER' -> pushMode(UNTILSEMI) ;

mode UNTILSEMI;
ENDSEMI   : ';'+ -> popMode ;
CONTENT   : ~[;]+ ;
```

the parser will be:

```
askStmt: ASK CONTENT ENDSEMI;
answerStmt: ASNWER CONTENT ENDSEMI;
```

my Problem: when there a semicolons inside of "strings", the tokenizer stops and the parser wont work..

i have no idea how to start. should i manipulate the lexer directly? can i do this with lexer-modes?

Comment: Why do you want `"How old are you?" INTO inAge` to be a single token? Do you just not care about those statements and want to ignore them? Even in that case it's probably easier to tokenize them properly (or semi-properly with an `UNKNOWN: .;` token in there) and then use `.*? ';'` in the parser.

Comment: @sepp2k the problem is, that all the content that is parsed (e.G. `ASK "How old are you?" INTO inAge;`) must be send to an other system. The provided syntax is just an example, The grammar is much more complex...

Comment: Then provide some real world examples. Posting (too) simplified examples will almost always lead to help/answers that will not fully cover real world input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see the need for lexical modes. Something like this would handle your example input correctly:

```
parse
 : ( question | answer )* EOF
 ;

question
 : ASK expression ( INTO ID )? SEMI
 ;

answer
 : ANSWER expression SEMI
 ;

expression
 : expression PLUS expression
 | STRING
 | ID
 ;

ASK    : 'ASK';
ANSWER : 'ANSWER';
INTO   : 'INTO';
ID     : [a-zA-Z]+;
PLUS   : '+';
SEMI   : ';';
SPACES : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip;
STRING : '"' ( ~[\\"] | '\\' . )* '"';
```

### EDIT

Even without expressions, so only a few tokens, I don't see the need for lexical modes:

```
parse
 : ( question | answer )* EOF
 ;

question
 : ASK ~SEMI* SEMI OTHER*
 ;

answer
 : ANSWER ~SEMI* SEMI OTHER*
 ;

ASK    : 'ASK';
ANSWER : 'ANSWER';
SEMI   : ';';
STRING : '"' ( ~[\\"] | '\\' . )* '"';
OTHER  : ~[";];
```

which will parse your example input as follows:

[image]

Comment: thanks, but the problem i have is how to read everything up to the semicolon into one token. The grammar of the ASK (or ANSWER) command is totally unknown and the content has to be passed to a subsystem.
My approach in the question I asked works so far, but: at the first occurrence of a semicolon the lexer stops. This is a problem with string literals (surrounded by " or ') inside the command.

Comment: See my **EDIT**. A single token is not going to work: by making such long tokens, you'll end up with `ASK` and `ANSWER` being consumed by these large tokens. The way I propose will still get you the original text of everything between `ASK` and `;`